# ConTeXt - weird vertical alignment in multicolumn enumeration

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, itemize

When I type math in a multicolumn enumeration, there is a gap in vertical alignment if I use fractions or matrices.

```
\startitemize[ columns, three]
    \item $\frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}$
    \item $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}$
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

I can fix it with a tricky `phantom`

```
\startitemize[ columns, three]
    \item $\frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1} \phantom{\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}}$
    \item $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}$
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Is there a cleaner way ?

**Edit** may be the same issue : is it possible to have a fixed  interline space (in order to get an aspect similar to a table with fixed lineheight and without frame). For example this doesn't look good

```
\starttext
    \startitemize[n, columns, packed]
    \item $f(x) = 3\text{e}^{2x+1}-\ln(2x-3)$
    \item $g(t) = \frac{t^2-3t+2}{t-1}$
    \item $h(x) = \sin(\omega t + x)$
    \item $i(t) = \sin(\omega t + x)$
    \item $j(t) = \frac{\text{e}^{2t}-1}{\text{e}^{-2t}+1}$
    \item $k(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$
    \item $\ell(t) = \frac{1}{2+\ln(t)}$
    \item $m(x) = \sqrt{1+\ln(x)}$
    \item $n(x) = \sqrt{1+\ln(1+x^2)}$
    \item $p(x) = \ln(1+\text{e}^x)$
    \item $q(x) = \ln(x+\text{e}^{x^2})$
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what, if anything, that has changed. You can try this (I changed your `\text{e}` into `\mathrm{e}`):

```
\defineitemgroup[JMB]

\setupitemgroup[JMB][columns,three,packed]

\setupitemgroup[
    grid=no,
    inner={\setupinterlinespace[24pt]},
]

\starttext
\samplefile{ward}

\startitemgroup[JMB]
      \startitem $\frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}$ \stopitem
      \startitem $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}$           \stopitem
      \startitem $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}$             \stopitem
      \startitem $\frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}$ \stopitem
      \startitem $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}$           \stopitem
      \startitem $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}$             \stopitem
\stopitemgroup

\samplefile{ward}

\startitemgroup[JMB][n,two]
    \startitem $ f(x) = 3\mathrm{e}^{2x+1}-\ln(2x-3)$                 \stopitem
    \startitem $ g(t) = \frac{t^2-3t+2}{t-1}$                         \stopitem
    \startitem $ h(x) = \sin(\omega t + x)$                           \stopitem
    \startitem $ i(t) = \sin(\omega t + x)$                           \stopitem
    \startitem $ j(t) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{-2t}+1}$ \stopitem
    \startitem $ k(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$                                 \stopitem
    \startitem $ \ell(t) = \frac{1}{2+\ln(t)}$                        \stopitem
    \startitem $ m(x) = \sqrt{1+\ln(x)}$                              \stopitem
    \startitem $ n(x) = \sqrt{1+\ln(1+x^2)}$                          \stopitem
    \startitem $ p(x) = \ln(1+\mathrm{e}^x)$                          \stopitem
    \startitem $ q(x) = \ln(x+\mathrm{e}^{x^2})$                      \stopitem
\stopitemgroup

\samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

[image: image with some itemizations]